# Asserting list of elements follow a rule with JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, promise, chai

I have a set of titles that all look like:

```
<div class='items'>
  * Some | Text *
</div>
```

or

```
<div class='items'>
  * Some more | Text *
</div>
```

Given that there are numerous blocks that follow those two patterns on the page, I would like to loop through them all and ensure that they all contain the pattern '* Some [more] | Text *' where [more] is optional and * is anything.

I currently have:

```
yield browser

...Some code...

.elements('.items')
 .then((elementList)=>{
  for(var i = 0; i < elementList.value.length; i++){

   this.elementIdText(elementList.value[i].ELEMENT)
    .then((currElement)=>{
      var str = currElement.value;
      if(str.indexOf("Some | Text") == -1 || str.indexOf("Some more | Text") == -1){
       assert.ok(false, 'invalid string');
      }
    })

  }
 })
```

However it seems that the asserts get ignored since they're inside a for loop (which i guess messes everything up since it's not asynch??)

Although I want the program to throw a fail as soon as one of the strings do not match the required pattern so I assumed a loop was necessary.

Is there a good way to do this?

The current behavior if I placed a console.log inside the for loop:

```
Command: find element
Command: find element
... n times
log: element 1 text
log: element 2 text
... n times
```

Where it should be:

```
Command
log
Command
log
... n times
```

Comment: It's probable that the selenium test doesn't know when to end the asynchronous test, and so doesn't wait for your asserts. You need to see how to make selenium tests wait.

Comment: Where would the wait go? I updated the question to show behavior and no .pause command brings me to that (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution without using q promise library!

(Alternative would have been to use the .all([]).then() function that q provides)

```
yield browser

...Some code...

.elements('.items')
 .then((elementList)=>{

  var chain = this; // start a promise chain

  for(var i = 0; i < elementList.value.length; i++){

   // add this whole promise to the chain every iteration
   chain = chain.elementIdText(elementList.value[i].ELEMENT)
            .then((currElement)=>{
              var str = currElement.value;
              if(str.indexOf("Some | Text") == -1 || str.indexOf("Some more | Text") == -1){
               assert.ok(false, 'invalid string');
              }
            })

  }

  // Simply return the chain of promises created
  return chain;
 })
```

The idea was that the .then is just a promise that what's inside it will eventually be evaluated. This meant that the stuff inside may not be evaluated until after the test has completed.

Although one solution would have been to add pauses (maybe?), by creating a chain of promises, the next promise doesn't get evaluated until the previous one, and as a result, the test ends after all code is run.

Comment: @charlie cant mark own answer as answered for 2 days.

Answer (score -1):

below way may helps you..

```
    //assume that i am loding list of elements by driver
    List<String> data=new ArrayList<>();

    data.add("murali");

    data.add("murali [selenium]");

    //for loop to iterate list
    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){

        //using asserting to check data brought by list with actual
        //you can change here as per requirement
        //as know any one in list fails then it throws fail with out checking remaining elements in list
        assert data.get(i)=="murali" || data.get(i)=="murali [selenium]";
    }
```

i think you may need to adjust assert command above as i just used equals there but not same your case.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: any reason why it is down voted? if you have reason then specify before down voting...

Comment: I wasn't asking simply how to loop through elements, I was asking how to implement a loop within an asynchronous promise chain that runs at the expected time.